# Sobolev Inequality of Uniform Norm - Proof Explanation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

In Brezis book, in the chapter of the Sobolev spaces, there is a proof for the inequality 
\begin{gather}
\| u \|_{L^{\infty}(I)} \leq C \| u \|_{W^{1.p}(I)}
\end{gather}
for every $u \in W^{1,p}(I)$ and $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ where he sets $I =\mathbb{R}$. Then he proceeds by setting $G(s) = |s|^{p-1}s$ and taking the function $w = G(v) \in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$. He computes
\begin{gather}
w^\prime = G^\prime(v)v^\prime = p |v|^{p-1}v^\prime
\end{gather} 
and thus for $x \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{gather}
G(v(x)) = \int_{-\infty}^x p |v|^{p-1}v^\prime(t)\ \mathrm{d}t
\end{gather}
He says that by Hölder's inequality 
\begin{gather}
|v(x)|^p \leq p \|v\|^{p-1}_p \|v^\prime\|_p
\end{gather}
From which he concludes that 
\begin{gather}
\| v \|_{\infty} \leq C \|v\|_{W^{1,p}}
\end{gather}
and then by density he proceeds to prove the claim.

I quite don't get how he passes through the last two steps, after defining the function $G(v(x))$. Can you please explain me the procedure in a bit more detail? Also, do you have any alternative prove? Particularly, I don't understand the motivation behind the definition of $G(s)$.

Thanks!

Comment: The same question was asked last week. Here is an alternate proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957959/sobolev-inequality-on-interval/2958104#2958104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is best to first consider $p=1$. In this case $G$ is simply the identity and the proof simplifies to
$$
\lvert v(x)\rvert=\left\lvert\int_{-\infty}^x v'(t)\,dt\right\rvert\leq \int_{-\infty}^x\lvert v'(t)\rvert\,dt\leq \lVert v'\rVert_{L^1}.
$$
Now we can take the supremum over $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and obtain $\lVert v\rVert_{L^\infty}\leq \lVert v'\rVert_{L^1}\leq \lVert v\rVert_{W^{1,1}}$.

The (rough) idea in the general case is to run the same proof, but apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to $\lvert v\rvert^p$ instead of $v$. The function $G$ is really just a replacement for $\lvert\cdot\rvert^p$ that repairs the non-differentiablity at $0$.

Let's now come to the steps you don't understand. Taking absolute values on both sides, your third equality reads
$$
\lvert v(x)\rvert^p=p\left\lvert \int_{-\infty}^x \lvert v\rvert^{p-1}v'\,dt\right\rvert.
$$
Next we apply Hölder's inequality with exponents $p/(p-1)$ and $p$ to the factors $\lvert v\rvert^{p-1}$ and $v'$ in the integral:
$$
\left\lvert\int_{-\infty}^x \lvert v\rvert^{p-1}v'\,dt\right\rvert\leq \left(\int_{-\infty}^x (\lvert v\rvert^{p-1})^{p/(p-1)}\,dt\right)^{(p-1)/p}\left(\int_{-\infty}^x \lvert v'\rvert^p\,dt\right)^{1/p}\leq \lVert v\rVert_{L^p}^{p-1}\lVert v'\rVert_{L^p}.
$$
Thus
$$
\lVert v\rVert_{L^\infty}\leq p^{1/p}\lVert v\rVert_{L^p}^{(p-1)/p}\lVert v'\rVert_{L^p}^{1/p}.
$$
In the last step we apply Young's inequality with exponents $p/(p-1)$ and $p$ to get
$$
\lVert v\rVert_{L^\infty}\leq C(\lVert v\rVert_{L^p}+\lVert v'\rVert_{L^p})=C\lVert v\rVert_{W^{1,p}}.
$$
Here all the fancy factors with $p$ where absorded in the constant $C$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I got it now! For the last step I think that it's $\|v\|_{W^{1,p}}=(\|v\|^p_{L^p}+\|v^\prime\|^p_{L_p})^{1/p}$, isn't it? But this makes only a difference in $C$ so it's ok.

Comment: @ares: Different authors use different conventions. In the end all these norms are equivalent, so it only influenes the constant $C$ as you said.